# How do you calculate the radiant for Kreutz Sungrazer comets? where in the sky do I look?

Tags: astronomy, comets

According to wikipedia:

> All known members of the [Kreutz Sungrazer] group up until 1965 had almost identical orbital inclinations at about 144°, as well as very similar values for the longitude of perihelion at 280–282°, with a couple of outlying points probably due to uncertain orbital calculations.

This longitude of 280 deg seems to point in the direction of the Orion constellation. However, the radiant would seem to be 180 degrees away (opposite) since I expect the radiant to point to the location of the apehelion.

I'm also wondering if there is any reason behind the apparent mirror image similarity (or otherwise some connection) between the sungrazers and the orionids, I found this image on pinterest

http://www.pinterest.com/pin/129197083031621626/

[image]

and this picture is actually what peeked my interest in wanting to know where in the sky the radiant for the sungrazers is.

FWIW the approximate RA of the orionids radiant seems to be roughly that of Saiph's, or 05h 47m 45 seems to translate to a longitude of -93 deg = 267 deg which, as I noted above, lies close to the perihelion of the sungrazers (http://math.mercyhurst.edu/~griff/courses/webmapping/RA_convert.php).

[--edit: oops it appears the orientation of the pic is "upside" down, the red star I mistook for Saiph there in Orion constellation actually seems to be Betelguese whose longitude is -91 deg = 269 deg. Comparing with the stars shown in Stellarium, the radiant seems to lie right in the middle part of Gemini, at RA of 7 hours = longitude of -75 deg = 285 ]

[--edit 2: 
http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?ID=dK11W030;orb=1;cov=0;log=0;cad=0#orb
contains a jpl orbit diagram for comet lovejoy--an example of a Kreutz sungrazer; the orbit diagram shows that the RA of the APHELION--not perihelion-- of lovejoy is aligned roughly with gemini (or jupiter currently), so now I am completely confused and am wondering if there is a typo in the wiki sungrazer page, or what the misunderstanding on my part is. ]

If anyone can point me to where in the sky the sungrazer radiant (such as nearest star/s) is it would be really appreciated from me.